# Django rendering a db field in the template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**Could anyone correct my code?** 
Background:
The user, once on the 'start.html' template, will enter their name and press submit. Then on the next template, 'game.html', there should be a paragraph tab that contains that users name.
Problem:
I must be writting something incorrectly because the user's name does not render on the 'game.html' template. Or, I could also be storing it wrong. Any suggestions or corrections would be very appreciated!

models.py - fp

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    #first player name
    fp_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

forms.py - I'm not sure if this is actually needed...?

```
from django import forms

class PlayerInfo(forms.Form):
    fp_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First player name')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
import os
from .forms import PlayerInfo
from .models import Player

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def start(request):
    if request.method == 'Post':
        form = PlayerInfo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = Player()
            obj.fp_name = form.cleaned_data['fp_name']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PlayerInfo()                      
    return render(request, 'start.html')

def game(request):
    return render_to_response('game.html', {'obj': Player.objects.all()})
```

start.html - Meant to submit player one's name

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block botRow %}
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="fp_name">First Player Name</label>
    <input id="fp_name" type="text" name="fp_name" maxlength="30" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

game.html - Meant to render the player one's name

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block midRow %}
<p>{{ obj.fp_name }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You are not making use of the form, and neither sending it to `start.html`, also on `game.html` you are sending every users registered in your website, you have to send the data of the user who have filled the form.

Comment: you have to send specific user to game.html you are sending all the user to game.html

Answer (score 0):

in your `game.html` the `obj` is query set of all `Users`, so you should walk through the list, look on block [for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in the docs:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block midRow %}

    {% for user in obj %}
        <p>{{ user.fp_name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using User.objects.all() you are getting a Collection of all site's users. It isn't current user. So, the collection doesn't have parameter fp_name. Use request.user to get current logged in user.

Also, there is some redundancy in your code:

1. Django contains User class with ability to store First Name out of the box. So, you don't need to declare it at all. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User
2. There is special class of forms - ModelForm. It helps you to map model's fields to form's fields as fast as possible. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/)
3. There is special class of views - CreateView. It helps you to realize basic logic of model creating. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView)
4. Forms intended to save your time. So, in templates it's better to use built-in rendering engine of forms, than to declare their fields manually. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-template)
5. If game.html is permitted only for registered users it's a good idea to use @login_required decorator to restrict access to this part of the site.

Comment: Well, my goal is to declare my own because this is a 'table top' game. So it will ask 'first player' for their name, and also 'second player' for their name. So I'm not sure that the builtin User class would be helpful. There are also no permissions.

Comment: I really don't understand the difference between your class and Django's builin User. If you need some additional fields for this class you can add them without any problems. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user)

Comment: I’ve renamed the class to Player. I don’t actually want to use the built in User at all. I just need a name field for two players